# Long text pushing other elements off screen with react native

Tags: css, layout, flexbox, react-native

I'm trying to build a layout in React-Native using Flexbox and I'm having trouble when the text is long. I want the layout to look like this:

[image: Desired Layout]

However, when the blue text gets long, it pushes the date off of the right side of the screen like this:

[image]

I'm intentionally making the text stay on 1 line. What I want is for the blue text to expand as much as possible without making the text shrink. I'm new to RN and my work with CSS is very limited so I don't have much experience doing things like this. Here is my stylesheet code:

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  textContainer: {
    flex: 1
  },
  separator: {
    height: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#dddddd'
  },
  title: {
    fontSize: 25,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    color: '#48BBEC'
  },
  subtitle: {
    fontSize: 20,
    color: '#656565'
  },
  dateContainer: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'flex-end'
  },
  rowContainer: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    padding: 10
  }
});
```

And, finally, my layout code:

```
<TouchableHighlight
    underlayColor='#dddddd'>
      <View style={styles.rowContainer}>
          <View  cstyle={styles.textContainer}>
            <Text numberOfLines={1} style={styles.title}>{rowData.name}</Text>
            <Text style={styles.subtitle}>{rowData.teacher}</Text>
          </View>
          <View style={styles.dateContainer}>
            <Text style={styles.subtitle}>{result}</Text>
          </View>
        <View style={styles.separator}/>
      </View>
    </TouchableHighlight>
```

Comment: Just a suggestion - try giving the dateContainer a min-width value?

Comment: I tried that but then the blue text goes under the date text

Comment: @beyerss not sure I understand whats the required functionality, what should happen when the text is too long?

Comment: How about trying with max-width for "textContainer" class?

Comment: I want the blue text to just truncate (show a "..." on the end of the string).

Comment: I don't *think* I can use a maxWidth because the max width would be dependent on the screen size. If there is a way to set that size dynamically, that would work.

Comment: Not sure in Flexbox, but as per my CSS knowledge you can do it by giving value in percentage for maxWidth.

Comment: If I do percentages, that would leave, potentially, way too much space for the date. For example, a tablet would have much more white space than a phone. So far this is the best solution but I would expect to have a better way to do this so that the title can grow all the way up to the date text.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/36247140/3597276

Comment: @Michael_B Suggestion does not seem to work in React Native

Answer (score 5):

Remove `flex: 1` from `dateContainer` and add `flexWrap: 'wrap'` to `textContainer`.

```
textContainer: {
  flex: 1,
  flexWrap: 'wrap'
},
dateContainer: {
  justifyContent: 'center',
  alignItems: 'flex-end'
},
```

Answer (score 3):

On your `textContainer` style replace the `flex: 1` with `flexShrink: 1`

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to set a `width` on the text component you wish to truncate (even if it's 100% of it's container which is the flexbox child I imagine), and also set `numberOfLines` prop to 1 (or however many lines you want to allow). See docs here on ellipsize mode and number of lines.

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/text.html#ellipsizemode

Code example of what I explain above:

```
<View style={{display: 'flex', flexDirection: 'row', overflow: 'hidden'}}>
    <View>
      <Text
        numberOfLines={1}
        style={{width: '100%'}}>Text here that I want to truncate</Text>
      <Text
        numberOfLines={1}
        style={{width:'100%'}}>Another line of text</Text>
    </View>
    <View style={{width: 120}}>
        <Text>01/01/2017</Text>
    </View>
</View>
```

If you're still having issues, it's possible you'll need to also use `overflow: hidden` in your text component style.

Comment: I cannot get this to work, I have tried both with and without `overflow: hidden` in the text components.

Answer (score 2):

To solve your problem, remove the `flex: 1` from the `dateContainer` and it won't go off the screen.

```
dateContainer: {
  //flex: 1, line removed
  justifyContent: 'center',
  alignItems: 'flex-end'
},
```

Add the `flex: 1` to your `rowContainer` as follows:

```
rowContainer: {
   flex: 1, //Line added
   flexDirection: 'row',
   padding: 10
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this is adding `flexGrow: 0` to the element that is pushing others away.

Answer (score -1):

I ended up solving this by measuring the parent view's width (with the `onLayout` callback) and then setting the width of the text's parent to the remainder.

This means having some state in the component, but it could be turned in to  a general component with a left-side dynamic-sized component and a right-side static component.